# Getting syntax error while binding label to StringProperty

Tags: java, javafx, bind

I am just starting to learn javafx.I am trying to make a simple application where you enter into a textfield and simultaniously give it out via the label.
Heres the main class

```
package testing;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class testing extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane RootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage=primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("First Application");
        initRootLayout();
        initProjectTest();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public void initRootLayout() {
        try{    FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(testing.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            RootLayout=(BorderPane)loader.load();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(RootLayout));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initProjectTest() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(testing.class.getResource("view/ProjectTest.fxml"));
            AnchorPane ProjectTest=(AnchorPane)loader.load();
            RootLayout.setCenter(ProjectTest);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller class

```
package testing.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ProjectTestController {

    @FXML
    private Label label1=new Label();
    @FXML
    private TextField textfield1=new TextField();


    label1.textProperty().bind(textfield1.textProperty());

}
```

If I try to implement it via a button where the text is updated everytime I click the button(via a `onAction` function) the code works fine. However I get syntax error when I try to bind. I tried to search for answers but none of were having syntax errors.

Comment: Can you give us the error

Comment: You have a statement in the middle of your `ProjectTestController` class. This is illegal. Statements must be inside methods, constructors, or initialization blocks.

Comment: Unrelated: You are manually creating instances of your `Label` and `TextField` yet they are annotated with `FXML`. Don't do this. Assuming you have corresponding `fx:id` attributes in your FXML file these fields are going to be injected by the `FXMLLoader` anyway. I suggest reading [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks a lot. Seems I need to study java also since my basics arent clear. It worked after I created an initialize method. Any source you would recommend for learning java? 
And yes my label had fx-id attribute in FXMl file but I manually created instances cause I read somewhere that it may cause a null pointer exception. Now I understand that was the case when the person doesnt have a FXML file linked to the label. Thanks again.

Comment: A simple Google search of "Java Tutorials" will give you many results. For instance, there is the [_tutorialspoint_](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm) website. There's also the tutorials put out by _Oracle_ themselves: [_The Java Tutorials_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/?sess=16e492aba137894101940f7f88d9f51f). The _Oracle_ tutorials are only updated to Java 8; I don't know about _tutorialspoint_.

Comment: If you can get books there is also _Effective Java_ by Joshua Bloch. I believe the most recent version is the 3rd Edition.